# How to avoid need for dependency injection for union types in Component c-tor?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I have two components (which could be made implementations of a common base class/interface).

The automatic dependency injection mechanism for constructors of components does not work for my case where a common child component of these two components need to access their specific parent component.

What should I do to still have a single type of subcomponent for both parent types?

## Source code

### clock-view component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { Clock } from "../clock";

import { ClocksFlowViewComponent } from "../clocks-flow-view/clocks-flow-view.component";
import { ClocksDataGridComponent } from '../clocks-data-grid/clocks-data-grid.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clock-view',
  templateUrl: './clock-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clock-view.component.scss']
})
export class ClockViewComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() clock: Clock;

  constructor(
    private parentCollectionView: ClocksFlowViewComponent
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onClicked(c: Clock)
  {
    for (let c2 of this.parentCollectionView.clocks)
    {
      c2.selected = false;
    }

    c.selected = true;
  }
}
```

### clocks-data-grid component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Clock } from '../clock';
import { ClockService } from "../clock.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clocks-data-grid',
  templateUrl: './clocks-data-grid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clocks-data-grid.component.scss']
})
export class ClocksDataGridComponent implements OnInit {

  static selectedClock : Clock | null;
  clocks : Clock[];

  constructor(
    private clockService: ClockService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getClocks();
  }

  getClocks(): void
  {
    this.clockService.getClocks()
      .subscribe(clocks => this.clocks = clocks);
  }

}
```

## clocks-flow-view component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Clock } from '../clock';
import { ClockService } from "../clock.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clocks-flow-view',
  templateUrl: './clocks-flow-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clocks-flow-view.component.scss']
})
export class ClocksFlowViewComponent implements OnInit {

  static selectedClock : Clock | null;
  clocks : Clock[];

  constructor(
    private clockService: ClockService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getClocks();
  }

  getClocks(): void
  {
    this.clockService.getClocks()
      .subscribe(clocks => this.clocks = clocks);
  }
}
```

### The templates

Currently the templates for the data grid and for the flow view are the same:

```html
<div *ngFor="let clock of clocks">
    <app-clock-view [clock]="clock"></app-clock-view>
</div>
```

But they will differ.

The template of the clock-view component is:

```html
<div class="clock-view" (click)="onClicked(clock)" [class.selected]="clock.selected">
    <h2>{{clock.id}}. {{clock.tag}}</h2>
    <textarea [(ngModel)]="clock.tag" placeholder="clock tag here" class="clock-tag-textarea"></textarea>
</div>
```

When visiting http://localhost:4200/data-grid, I get this error in the Chrome console:

```
core.js:38781 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
ClocksDataGridComponent.html:4 ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ClockViewComponent -> ClocksFlowViewComponent]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ClockViewComponent -> ClocksFlowViewComponent]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ClocksFlowViewComponent!
    at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:39072:27)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:53990:24)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:53916:16)
    at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:53766:20)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:53990:24)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:53916:16)
    at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:53766:20)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:64953:29)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:66019:16)
    at resolveDep (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:66550:45)
View_ClocksDataGridComponent_1 @ ClocksDataGridComponent.html:4
logError @ core.js:45546
handleError @ core.js:6066
(anonymous) @ core.js:41058
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:359
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
runOutsideAngular @ core.js:39572
tick @ core.js:41055
(anonymous) @ core.js:40893
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:359
onInvoke @ core.js:39699
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:358
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
run @ core.js:39511
next @ core.js:40890
schedulerFn @ core.js:35336
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:185
next @ Subscriber.js:124
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
next @ Subject.js:39
emit @ core.js:35298
checkStable @ core.js:39642
onHasTask @ core.js:39719
hasTask @ zone-evergreen.js:411
_updateTaskCount @ zone-evergreen.js:431
_updateTaskCount @ zone-evergreen.js:264
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:185
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone-evergreen.js:559
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:542
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:381
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:211
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:231
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone-evergreen.js:845
then @ zone-evergreen.js:955
bootstrapModule @ core.js:40600
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
0 @ main.ts:18
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
ClocksDataGridComponent.html:4 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 2, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
View_ClocksDataGridComponent_1 @ ClocksDataGridComponent.html:4
logError @ core.js:45546
handleError @ core.js:6071
(anonymous) @ core.js:41058
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:359
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
runOutsideAngular @ core.js:39572
tick @ core.js:41055
(anonymous) @ core.js:40893
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:359
onInvoke @ core.js:39699
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:358
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
run @ core.js:39511
next @ core.js:40890
schedulerFn @ core.js:35336
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:185
next @ Subscriber.js:124
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
next @ Subject.js:39
emit @ core.js:35298
checkStable @ core.js:39642
onHasTask @ core.js:39719
hasTask @ zone-evergreen.js:411
_updateTaskCount @ zone-evergreen.js:431
_updateTaskCount @ zone-evergreen.js:264
runTask @ zone-evergreen.js:185
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone-evergreen.js:559
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:542
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:381
scheduleTask @ zone-evergreen.js:211
scheduleMicroTask @ zone-evergreen.js:231
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone-evergreen.js:845
then @ zone-evergreen.js:955
bootstrapModule @ core.js:40600
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
0 @ main.ts:18
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
client:52 [WDS] Live Reloading enabled.
```

The problem, succintly expressed, is that dependency injection in constructors does not work with union types (in my case `ClocksFlowViewComponent | ClocksDataGridComponent`). Here is the problem, if I put an union type it throws a runtime error, and if I put two parameters, for one it fails with a runtime error for this too, and I do not know the most correct alternative.

```js
...
  constructor(
    private parentCollectionView: ClocksFlowViewComponent 
  ) { }
...
```

The GitHub repo is [here](https://github.com/silviubogan/ng-timed-silver).

This is my first day with Angular. Thank you.

## Update 1

What I am trying to achieve is in the `onClicked` method in the `clock-view` component. I want to know which `clock-view` is selected. In future I might want to have complex selection mechanisms (multiple selection, with Ctrl, Shift, rubberband rectangle, mouse click).

Comment: that dependency on the parent could probably be removed. Can you try to explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @maxime1992 I have added an update at the end of the question. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! But not quite what I was thinking of. If you were to delegate that task to someone who doesn't know anything about the project, what would you tell him? "The final goal is to have.... When I do this action I'd expect that to happen..." etc. I'm pretty sure we could come up with a better architecture that'd simplify that and remove the dependency on the parent component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can provide all of your container components as some token (which will be the same for all possible containers), so their children will be able to inject them

```
const CONTAINER_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<ContainerInterface>('Container Token');
....
@Component({
...
providers: [{provide: CONTAINER_TOKEN, useExisting: ClocksFlowViewComponent }]
})
export class ClocksFlowViewComponent {
}
...
@Component({
...
providers: [{provide: CONTAINER_TOKEN, useExisting: ClocksDataGridComponent }]
})
export class ClocksDataGridComponent {
}
...
export class ClockViewComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() clock: Clock;

  constructor(
    @Inject(CONTAINER_TOKEN ) private parentCollectionView: ContainerInterface
  ) { }
```

Comment: Where would be the best place for your first line (`const CONTAINER_TOKEN...`), in which file? Thank you.

Comment: it depends on your project. I would place all containers and their token in one directory as they are connected

Comment: But global variables are not allowed in Angular. Am I right?

Comment: JFYI if containers had a base class that class could be a token

Comment: it is possible to use global cars with angular, but why? it will restrict your app to only browser. a good written app can be run with ionic  or angular universal